# IOS Restkit null mapping result

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

I'm unable to map my JSON to model with RestKit. Logger on XCode says

```
2013-09-12 16:35:00.543 EMoney[1291:342f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:902 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x20155890> for 'EMEcommerceInquiryResponse' object. Mapping values from object {
} to object *nil description* with object mapping (null)
2013-09-12 16:35:00.550 EMoney[1291:342f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:571 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'status'
```

Here is the json response

```
response.body={"status":"NOT_ENOUGH_CREDITS","statusdesc":"no credits"}
```

Here is my mapping code

```
RKObjectMapping *ecommerceInquiryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[EMEcommerceInquiryResponse class]];
    [ecommerceInquiryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"status",@"statusdesc"]];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseEcommerceInquiryDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:ecommerceInquiryMapping
                                                                                                   pathPattern:EM_API_SPECIAL_OFFER_INQUIRY
                                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseEcommerceInquiryDescriptor];
```

And here is my object class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EMEcommerceInquiryResponse : NSObject
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *status;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *statusdesc;
@end
```

This is the log when I tried to print the status

```
2013-09-12 17:06:55.042 EMoney[1343:907] STATUS (null)
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong with my code? I use similar code for other mappings and they work fine.

Comment: What is `EMEcommerceInquiryResponse`? How are you making the request?

Comment: Meant to ask what `EM_API_SPECIAL_OFFER_INQUIRY` is and how you're making the request...